# Heroku request timeout when Memcachier reaches cache limit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, timeout, memcached

I have a Rails app deployed to Heroku using Memcachier (Dalli as client). I'm using the free add-on (which offers a 25 MB cache).

We started to receive request timeouts from heroku and, after debugging, we found out that manually flushing Memcachier solved the problem.

Timeouts occur when Memcachier reaches levels near its limit, like 20 MB (when limit is 25 MB).

Why Memcachier doesn't free cache space with time? Is there any **missing configuration** to tell Memcachier to **flush when cache reach certain size**?

My conf:

application.rb

```
config.cache_store = :dalli_store
```

production.rb

```
client = Dalli::Client.new
config.action_dispatch.rack_cache = {
    :metastore    => client,
    :entitystore  => client,
    :allow_reload => false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try updating your `production.rb` to include `socket_timeout` and `socket_failure_delay` options.

```
require 'dalli'
cache = Dalli::Client.new((ENV["MEMCACHIER_SERVERS"] || "").split(","),
                    {:username => ENV["MEMCACHIER_USERNAME"],
                     :password => ENV["MEMCACHIER_PASSWORD"],
                     :failover => true,
                     :socket_timeout => 1.5,
                     :socket_failure_delay => 0.2
                    })
```

-- OR --

If you are using **Puma**, you need to have the `connection_pool` gem installed.

Gemfile

```
gem 'connection_pool'
```

And this configuration in your production.rb

```
config.cache_store = :dalli_store,
                    (ENV["MEMCACHIER_SERVERS"] || "").split(","),
                    {:username => ENV["MEMCACHIER_USERNAME"],
                     :password => ENV["MEMCACHIER_PASSWORD"],
                     :failover => true,
                     :socket_timeout => 1.5,
                     :socket_failure_delay => 0.2,
                     :pool_size => 5
                    }
```