# Heroku Memcachier Server Error

Tags: python, django, heroku, memcached, newrelic

recently I've been experiencing a periodic error that results in a Heroku server crash, and I believe it to be originating from the MemCachier addon. The logs are  found below:

`» 09:43:19.038 2015-03-02 15:44:00.567613+00:00 app web.2 - - Traceback (most recent call last): File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_pylibmc/memcached.py", line 106, in set MIN_COMPRESS) File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/newrelic-2.18.1.15/NX/newrelic/api/memcache_trace.py", line 43, in _nr_wrapper_memcache_trace_ return wrapped(*args, **kwargs) MemcachedError: error 47 from memcached_set: SERVER HAS FAILED AND IS DISABLED UNTIL TIMED RETRY, host: mc5.dev.ec2.memcachier.com:11211 -> libmemcached/connect.cc:592`

`» 09:44:13.053 2015-03-02 15:44:00.305034+00:00 app web.2 - - Traceback (most recent call last): File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_pylibmc/memcached.py", line 96, in get return super(PyLibMCCache, self).get(key, default, version) File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/cache/backends/memcached.py", line 64, in get val = self._cache.get(key) File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/newrelic-2.18.1.15/NX/newrelic/api/memcache_trace.py", line 43, in _nr_wrapper_memcache_trace_ return wrapped(*args, **kwargs) HostLookupError: error 2 from memcached_get(:1:django.contrib.sessions.cache): getaddrinfo() or getnameinfo() HOSTNAME LOOKUP FAILURE, Name or service not known, host: mc5.dev.ec2.memcachier.com:11211 -> libmemcached/connect.cc:179`

I believe the second error log originated because the cache lookup was not available after error #1 - but I'm having difficulty investigating the first error.

Currently we're on the dev plan of the Heroku addon, so maybe this could be due to running out of allowed connections? Is there any way to determine this aside from joining the paid plan?

Also curious as to why NewRelic is appearing everywhere. They must be wrapping the cache calls in order to trace them?

I have searched quite a bit and [this is the most relevant article I could find](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19666801/heroku-request-timeout-when-memcachier-reaches-cache-limit).

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: New Relic mentioned in the stack trace is incidental in this case. The agent does trace calls to certain Memcache modules (in this case pymemcache, which MemCachier uses under the hood). The problem looks to be directly with MemCachier/pymemcache.